# Container won't auto size to its content

Tags: html, css

I am making a form, following basic HTML and CSS rules online, however I'm now not sure why my container has stopped auto re-sizing to it's contents.

I've tried the following:

- Changing `overflow` from `hidden` to `relative`, which did help with the visibility of the contents but is still outside the container.
- Adding a `position:relative;` to the container but this did nothing.
- Removing the height and then tried changing `height` from `height:auto;` to `height:relative`.
- Checked if I have set anything to absolute positioning which I haven't. I tried adding an `overflow:auto;` which moved it back into the container but I don't want the scroll on the side...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b0cac7;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 80%;
  overflow: relative;
  position: relative;
  max-height: min-content;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 5%;
  border-radius: 0%;
  box-shadow: 20px 30px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #none;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
  border-radius: px;
  border: 2px solid #707070;
  outline: none;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #9c9c9c;
}

.container .form {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form .input-box {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-box label {
  color: #333;
}

.form .input-box input {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: rgb(39, 34, 34);
}

.form :where(.input-box input,
.select-box,
) {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #707070;
  margin-top: px;
  border: 2px solid #cfd1d6;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.column {
  margin: -1%;
  /*used -1 to reduce spaces between each textarea */
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#date {
  /*used -10 margin bottom to remove the space to heading below */
  margin-bottom: -10%;
}

.other {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1c093c;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #606060;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px 30px;
}

label i {
  color: #1c093c;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.flex-row {
  margin-top: -5%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-right: 0;
}

.column .input-box #name {
  margin-bottom: 20%%;
}

canvas#signature-pad {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.jSignature {
  background-color: rgb(151, 23, 23);
}

button#clear {
  height: 100%;
  background: #0e5272;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button#clear span {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: block;
}

textarea,
input {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-radius: 0.5%;
  border: 2px solid #cfd1d6;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border-color: #e2d847;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e4c749;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border-color: #e2d847;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e4c749;
}

h4 {
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: linear-gradient( 130deg, #6f6df4, #4c46f5);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .form .column {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  /*trying to style the button to be wrapped */
  .upload .up {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Form</title>
  <!--Google Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Stylesheet-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--Signaure pad link-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/4.1.7/signature_pad.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="container">
    <h1>Site Report Sheet</h1>
    <form action="#" class="form">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <label for="client">Client details</label>
          <textarea id="client" name="client" placeholder="Enter details here.." rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <label for="site">Site Name & Address</label>
          <textarea id="issue" name="issue" placeholder="Enter details here..." rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <div class="input-box">
          <label>WIS Number</label>
          <input type="text" required />
        </div>

        <div class="input-box" id="date">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" required />
        </div>
      </div>

      <br>
      <br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

      <!--This will be an open space for middle of Report-->


      <h4>THE ABOVE IS CERTIFIED CORRECT AND SYSTEM HAS BEEN LEFT IN <u>WORKING ORDER</u></h4> <br>

      <div class="column">
        <div class="input-box">
          <label id="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" required />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <!--Signature pad-->

      <label>Signature</label> <br><br>
      <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <canvas id="signature-pad" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-btn">
          <button id="clear"><span> Clear </span></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <div class="input-box">
          <label>On Behalf Of</label>
          <input type="text" required />
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <label>Position</label>
          <input type="text" required />
        </div>

        <div class="input-box" id="date">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" required />
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's due to the `margin-bottom: -10%;` on  `#date`, which moves the element out of the container. Just remove that:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #b0cac7;
}

.container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 80%;
    overflow: relative;
    position: relative;
    max-height: min-content;

    height: auto;
    padding: 3%;
    margin: 5%;
    border-radius: 0%;
    box-shadow: 20px 30px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#none;
    font-size:16px;
    resize:none;
    border-radius: px;
    border:2px solid #707070;
    outline:none;
}

textarea::placeholder {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #9c9c9c;
}

.container .form {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.form .input-box {
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-box label {
    color: #333;
}

.form .input-box input {
    position:relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: rgb(39, 34, 34);
}

.form :where(.input-box input, .select-box,) {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    outline:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #707070;
    margin-top: px;
    border: 2px solid #cfd1d6;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.column {
    margin: -1%; /*used -1 to reduce spaces between each textarea */
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 10px;  
}

#date { /*used -10 margin bottom to remove the space to heading below */
    /* margin-bottom: -10%; */
}

.other {
    margin-left: 20px;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1c093c;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}


.row {
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px,1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px 30px;
}
label i{
    color: #1c093c;
    font-size: 16px;
}


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.flex-row {
    margin-top: -5%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-right: 0;

}

.column .input-box #name {
    margin-bottom: 20%%;
}

canvas#signature-pad {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: crosshair;
}

.jSignature {
    background-color: rgb(151, 23, 23);
}

button#clear {
    height: 100%;
    background: #0e5272;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button#clear span {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: block;
}


textarea,
input {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 0.5%;
    border: 2px solid #cfd1d6;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #e2d847;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e4c749;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #e2d847;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e4c749;
}

h4 {
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(
        130deg,
        #6f6df4,
        #4c46f5
    );
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .form .column {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  
    /*trying to style the button to be wrapped */
    .upload .up {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Form</title>
    <!--Google Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--Signaure pad link-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/4.1.7/signature_pad.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <section class="container">
        <h1>Site Report Sheet</h1>
        <form action="#" class="form">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <label for="client">Client details</label>
                    <textarea id="client" name="client" placeholder="Enter details here.." rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <label for="site">Site Name & Address</label>
                    <textarea id="issue" name="issue"  placeholder="Enter details here..." rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>WIS Number</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="input-box" id="date">
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <input type="date" required />
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            
           <!--This will be an open space for middle of Report-->


            <h4>THE ABOVE IS CERTIFIED CORRECT AND SYSTEM HAS BEEN LEFT IN <u>WORKING ORDER</u></h4> <br>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label id="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
<br><br>
                  <!--Signature pad-->
                  
                <label>Signature</label> <br><br>
                <div class="flex-row">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <canvas id="signature-pad" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear-btn">
                        <button id="clear"><span> Clear </span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>On Behalf Of</label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Position</label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="input-box" id="date">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <input type="date" required />
                    </div>
                </div>

         

           





        </form>
    </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Johannes. I didn't realise margin bottoms set with a minus value had that effect. Noted for the future.